# Change dir after 'sudo -i', in one command

Tags: linux, bash, ssh, command, sudo

Is there a way to switch dir after doing `sudo -i` (in one command)?

We use lots of ssh connections on work, and it is a pain to manually set them up when you reboot your pc. So I'm trying to make aliases like `ssh remote-dev -t 'sudo -i; bash -l'`, which connects me to a machine and makes me root there (it is required to do that way; because of Kerberos we can't directly `ssh root@...`)

So what I would like to do now is expanding the above command in a way that I can also tell it to switch to a specific dir after the sudo, or open a specific file, or tail a logfile or something... Is that possible?

-- edit: Of course you could tell it to do some command everytime someone logs in via ssh. But this is a bad option, because only I want to have these commands to be executed; When other people connect to this machine, they probably want different commands.

-- edit: Sorry I posted it here, did not realize it is offtopic in stackoverflow

Comment: First change to directory & then sudo?

Comment: If the directory does not have exec permission (+x) for current user, permission only to root, try `sudo -i bash -c "cd /path/to/dir; exec bash"`

Comment: @anishsane: First cd and then sudo does not work, as then the current user changes dir, and when you do sudo the root user "starts" in his ~, and not in the dir of the previous user.
But the `ssh remote-dev -t 'sudo -i bash -c "cd /opt/; exec bash"'` works nicely, thanks!
Now what if I wanted for example to open it some files in vim (and maybe send that vim process to background)? Because the `"cd /opt/; vim /tmp/d1; exec bash"` does not work properly; e.g. I can not send it to background via [ctrl]+[z]

Comment: vim is curses based. don't expect to run it in background.

Comment: @anishsane: But when I manuelly open vim, I _can_ send it into background via ctrl+z o_O

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try

```
sudo -i bash -c "cd /path/to/dir; exec bash"
```

Comment: Though that does not work for vim strangely (instead of / additionally to cd), it is what I wanted to know. Thank you!